# Update Business Unit Subscription List - Unsubscribe Subscriber from List

Tags: api, soap-api, c#, marketing-cloud, .net

I have the list in my business unit. There are lots of subscribers. I need to be able to change the opt in opt out preferences for any subscriber from API call.

I found the next article http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/managing_subscribers_on_lists/

And here is my code... When I execute it, status is OK, but when I refresh the exacttarget page / list with subscribers, I don't see any changes.
How to manage Opt In / Opt Out preferences for any particular list and subscriber?

```
var sub = new Subscriber
{
    SubscriberKey = "10103-KZ-P-Cust",
    Client = new ClientID
    {
        ID = 11011214,
        IDSpecified = true
    }
};

var benList = new SubscriberList
{
    ID = 6851919,
    IDSpecified = true,
    Status = SubscriberStatus.Unsubscribed,
    Action = "Update"
};

sub.Lists = new[] { benList };

var soap = new SoapClient();

soap.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _login;
soap.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;

APIObject[] results;
string requestID;
string status;

UpdateResult[] updateResults = 
    soap.Update(new UpdateOptions(), new APIObject[] { sub }, out requestID, out status);
```

Comment: When you are refreshing the page, is it in the business unit you are trying to change, or in the top level all subscribers list?

Comment: That's inside my business unit (child), not in the default (parent) one.

Comment: Has the user you are passing in for credentials been given access to that specific business unit, as well?  Nothing immediately jumps out in code, but the c# isn't my normal language, so I'm going off examples.

Comment: Yes, that user was created for API usage. And I don't get any errors. status is OK, UpdateResult also says that Subscriber's List property exists.

Comment: I'll play around and try to reproduce this. I suspect that your API user doesn't have access to the business unit though.  Are you able to do any other api calls into business units?

Comment: Of course. I'm getting the subscribers by e-mail using this API user, I'm updating subscriber's global status to Active / Held / Unsibscribed also by using this API user. That's OK.

Comment: Subscribers live in the top level account as well. You may be seeing the top level and not the business unit.  Check the API users business unit associations in the admin section.  Also,  I assume the id you are passing in for the client is the BU id?

Comment: My API user is assotiated with 2 child business units (not the default / top level one). It has Administrator role. I'm passing associated business unit ID in ClientID.

Comment: I think we need refer to etplatinum support, right?

Comment: If you have platinum support,  go for it. Respond as an answer when you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Online documentation is incomplete.**

We need put `StatusSpecified = true;` in order to send changed status to ExactTarget.

**Full source code:**

```
var benList = new SubscriberList
{
    ID = 6851919,
    IDSpecified = true,
    Status = SubscriberStatus.Unsubscribed,
    StatusSpecified = true, // <==== THIS ONE WAS MISSING FOR PROPER WORK
    Action = "Update"
};
```

**This property was not listed neither here** http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/managing_subscribers_on_lists/
**nor here** http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/subscriberlist/

Comment: Be sure to mark this as the answer. Just click the checkmark.